# Terraform aws - Unable to create AWS SFTP server using terraform script

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create `AWS SFTP` server using `terraform` script.

I am able to validate using `terraform validate` command and able to get plan using `terraform plan` as well

but I am getting below error while trying to run `terraform apply` command

> Error: Error creating Transfer Server: InvalidRequestException: Must specify
> IdentityProviderType with IdentityProviderDetails
> on .terraform/modules/sftp/sftp.tf line 1, in resource "aws_transfer_server" "sftp":
> 1: resource "aws_transfer_server" "sftp" {
> [image]

I have provided the `identity_provider_type = "SERVICE_MANAGED"` in my script but still i am getting the error and unable to create AWS SFTP server.

Here is my scripts

**sftp.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
   version = "~> 2.0"
   region  = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_transfer_server" "sftp" {
  identity_provider_type = "SERVICE_MANAGED"
  invocation_role = "arn:aws:iam::<id>"

  tags = {
        NAME     = "test-sftp"
  }
}
```

**main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
    version = "~> 2.0"
    region  = "us-east-1"
}

module "sftp" {
    source = "/home/sasi/TerraForm/terraform-scripts/modules/sftp"
    aws-transfer-server-name = "test-sftp"
    iam-role-name-for-sftp = "test-sftp-role"
    s3-access-policy-name = "s3-specific-bucket-access"
    sftp-user-name = "sasi-sftp"
    sftp-s3-bucket-name = "/sasi-learn-test-bucket"
    ssh-public-key-file-location = "${file("/home/sasi/TerraForm/terraform-scripts/modules/sftp/rsa.pub")}"
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the AWS provider so I'd be tempted to [raise it as an issue there](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't need the `invocation_role` when `identity_provider_type` is `SERVICE_MANAGED`. Here's the information from the Terraform transfer server resource [page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/transfer_server.html#invocation_role):

```
invocation_role - (Optional) Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the IAM role used to authenticate the user account with an identity_provider_type of API_GATEWAY.
```

Since your `identity_provider_type` is not `API_GATEWAY`, you can probably try without providing the `invocation_role`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not resolving the error. I have tried by adding invocation_role property with valid role but still i am getting the same error as mentioned above

Comment: What are AWS provider and Terraform versions?

Comment: here is my aws provider version property version = "~> 2.0"

Comment: I have updated my main.tf(configuration) script as well

Comment: I could find the "terraform-provider-aws_v2.67.0_x4" file so seems like terraform aws provider 2.67.0 is the version to used when i run the script

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Can you also paste contents of the `sftp` module?

Comment: @SasikumarMurugesan: Marko is not suggesting that you *add* the `invocation_role` with a valid role, he is suggesting that you *remove* the `invocation_role` property altogether

Comment: @lxop I tried with and without invocation_role with valid role arn and getting the same error

Comment: I believe it is an issue with AWS provider as suggested by @ydaetskcoR

Comment: Could you post the output of `terraform plan`?

Comment: I understood from the original post that when you run `terraform validate` and `terraform plan` you don't get any errors.